# What is wrong in this Ajax/Javascript code?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to do a function that will show the clock on clicking a button but i can't get the clock to show up. I'm kinda new on this stuff and would really appreciate some help with this and also an explanation to what I've done wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01
Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>

function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
try {
req = new XMLHTTPRequest();
} catch(err1) {
    try {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (err2) {
        try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (err3) {
            req = false;
        }
    }
}
return req; 
}

var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();

function getServerTime() {
    var myurl = 'telltimeXML.php';
myRand = parseInt(Math.random()*9999999999999);
var modurl = myurl+"?rand="+myRand;
http.open("GET", modurl, true);
http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
http.send(null);
}

function useHttpResponse() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        if(http.status == 200) {
            var timeValue = http.responseXML
    .getElementsByTagName("timenow")[0];
        document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML
        =timeValue.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = '<img src="anim.gif">';
    }
}
</script>

<title>Ajax</title>
<style>
.displaybox {
width:150px;
background: #ffffff;
border:2px solid #000;
padding:10px;
font:24px normal verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#cccccc; text-align:center">
<h1>Ajax</h1>
<h2>Hamta tiden fran servern utan att uppdatera sidan</h2>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Hamta tiden fran servern" />
</form>
<div id="showtime" class="displaybox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the .PHP code.. (telltimeXML.php)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><clock1><timenow>"
.date('H:i:s)."</timenow></clock1>";
?>
```

Comment: what error is it showing in firebug console mood?

Comment: I not very familiar with that extension, I got it installed though.

Comment: install the add-on firebug. turn it on and go to firebug mood. Execute your ajax. then you might see what the problem is. unless you can debug ajax this is an easier way to find the errors

Comment: Can't see anything special that's wrong. But I could be misreading the add-on also, I don't really know. I wonder if there's anything obvious that fails in my code that I can't see but maybe someone else can.

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/errors

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to close the  **'**  in date finction in telltimeXML.php file .Replace this :

```
 header('Content-Type: text/xml');
 echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><clock1><timenow>".date('H:i:s)."</timenow></clock1>";
```

with

```
 header('Content-Type: text/xml');
 echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><clock1><timenow>".date('H:i:s')."</timenow></clock1>";
```

Comment: Did change that but it did no difference.. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some parentheses at the end of this line:

http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;

Comment: Tried but no difference to the result.

Comment: @p0rk try declaring this line as a variable:

myRand = parseInt(Math.random()*9999999999999);

good luck, hope it helps